# underscore.js each function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js. I loop through the `selectedCharges` array using underscore `each` function but I cannot access the `selectedCharges` variable inside the loop.

```
_.each(this.selectedCharges, function(selectedCharge, key){
    if(selectedCharge._id == charge._id){
        this.selectedCharges.splice(key,1); // get error from this line  
    }
});
```

Comment: remove this. in the if. this is your object you are currently iterating over

Comment: like this?   selectedCharges.splice(key,1);

Comment: don't post code in the comments. especially not without any explanation.

Comment: yes like this..

Comment: It gets error.  "Cannot find name 'selectedCharges' "

Comment: You should not mutate collection while iterating over it. Use `Array.prototype.filter` or corresponding underscore function.

Comment: add that with code as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) changes inside the loop, you can keep the same scope by binding your function with `this` using the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Code example:

```
_.each(this.selectedCharges, function(selectedCharge, key){
    if(selectedCharge._id == charge._id){
        this.selectedCharges.splice(key,1);  
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: still get the error. Cannot read property 'selectedCharges' of undefined

Comment: But then arrises another issue. mutating array within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays javascript has native support for most underscore features. See https://www.reindex.io/blog/you-might-not-need-underscore/.

The underscore answer is:

```
var filteredCharges = _.filter(this.selectedCharges, function(selectedCharge){
    return selectedCharge._id !== charge._id;
});
```

The native answer is:

```
const filteredCharges = this.selectedCharges.filter(selectedCharge => {
    return selectedCharge._id !== charge._id
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the third argument which is the collection itself.
For example

```
_.each(this.selectedCharges, function(selectedCharge, key, coll){

   if(selectedCharge._id == charge._id){
       coll.splice(key,1);
   }

});
```

Here is the documentation link: http://underscorejs.org/#each